# The getter 'length' was called on null for my _showErrorMessage Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I tried to show error messages for my LogIn Page, however, it did not work.
Everything else works fine, but when I want to use _showErrorMessage() method, the app will crush.

This is the part of all of my codes that involve _showErrorMessage()method.

```
class LogInPage extends StatefulWidget {
LogInPage({this.auth, this.onSignedIn});
final BaseAuth auth;
final VoidCallback onSignedIn;


@override
_LogInPageState createState() => _LogInPageState();
}

enum FormMode { LOGIN, SIGNUP }

class _LogInPageState extends State<LogInPage> {
final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

String _email;
String _password;
String _errorMessage = '';

FormMode _formMode = FormMode.LOGIN;
bool _isIos;
bool _isLoading;

// Check if form is valid before perform login or signup
bool _validateAndSave() {
final form = _formKey.currentState;
if (form.validate()) {
  form.save();
  return true;
  }
return false;
}

// Perform login or signup
void _validateAndSubmit() async {
setState(() {
  _errorMessage = "";
  _isLoading = true;
});
if (_validateAndSave()) {
  String userId = "";
  try {
    if (_formMode == FormMode.LOGIN) {
      userId = await widget.auth.signIn(_email, _password);
      print('Signed in: $userId');
    } else {
      userId = await widget.auth.signUp(_email, _password);
      widget.auth.sendEmailVerification();
      _showVerifyEmailSentDialog();
      print('Signed up user: $userId');
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });

    if (userId != null && userId.length > 0 && _formMode == FormMode.LOGIN) {
      widget.onSignedIn();
    }

  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      if (_isIos) {
        _errorMessage = e.details;
      } else
        _errorMessage = e.message;
    });
    }
  }
}


@override
void initState() {
_errorMessage = "";
_isLoading = false;
super.initState();
 }

void _changeFormToSignUp() {
_formKey.currentState.reset();
_errorMessage = "";
setState(() {
  _formMode = FormMode.SIGNUP;
  });
 }

 void _changeFormToLogin() {
_formKey.currentState.reset();
_errorMessage = "";
setState(() {
  _formMode = FormMode.LOGIN;
});
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
_isIos = Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS;
return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Organizer"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    ),
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _showBody(),
        _showCircularProgress(),
      ],
    ));
    }



  Widget _showBody(){
   return new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: new Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: new ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          _showEmailInput(),
          _showPasswordInput(),
          _showPrimaryButton(),
          _showSecondaryButton(),
          _showErrorMessage(),
        ],
      ),
    ));
     }
    Widget _showErrorMessage() {
    if (_errorMessage.length > 0 && _errorMessage != null) {
   return new Text(
    _errorMessage,
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 13.0,
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 1.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
  );
} else {
  return new Container(
    height: 0.0,
  );
 }
}
```

I understand what this error means, but I don't know how to solve it.
Please help me, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code

```
 if (_errorMessage.length > 0 && _errorMessage != null)
```

to this:

```
 if (_errorMessage != null && _errorMessage.length > 0)
```

**Explanation**
When an object is null, there are no properties to access. You were first checking the length property, even when the object was null. Moving the null check first ensures that properties won't be accessed on a null object.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps. Can I know why it works that way?

Comment: Happy to help :). Updated the answer with the explanation